# cv2 is not found at site-package folder of Python after cmake build

Tags: python, c++, windows, opencv, cmake

I'm trying to build opencv with CUDA function on Python 3.9.6
I set the paths related to Python3 without Python3_LIBRARY_DEBUG and checked that they are correct with cmake.
Build of opencv (with function of CUDA) worked without errors.

```
cmake --build "fullpath to build folder" --target INSTALL --config Release
```

but "cv2" folder is not found at site-package folder of Python after cmake build, and "install" folder is not found at build folder(that is set at "Where to build the binaries" on cmake)

【update】cmake settings

```
PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe
PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/include
PYTHON3_LIBRARY C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/libs/python39.lib
PYTHON3_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include
PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Lib/site-packages
CMAKE_PREFIX_INSTALL C:/Users/user/Desktop/build_4.5.0-2/install
```

【update】build folders after cmake build

```
├3rdparty/
├apps/
├bin/
├CmakeFiles/
├configured/
├data/
├doc/
├downloads/
├include/
├lib/
├modules/
├opencv2/
├python_loader/
├testdata/
├test-reports/
├tmp/
├win-install/
```

・OS:Windows 10 Pro for Workstation
・Python:3.9.6
・Cmake(GUI):3.20.5, Generator: Visual Studio 16 2019 
・opencv: 4.5.3, opencv_contrib:4.5.3

Answer (score -1):

**Step 0: Prerequisites**

- Download and install CUDA and cuDNN.
- Download and install CmakeGUI.
- Download and install Visual Studio Community Edition.
  Install with Desktop Development for C++ option.
- Download OpenCV source.
- Download OpenCV contrib. Make sure the version matches with
  OpenCV.
- Extract OpenCV and OpenCV contrib zip files.
- Make an empty folder called build.

**Step 1: Building OpenCV using CMake GUI**

- Open CMake GUI and browse for OpenCV source folder.
- Browse for make folder that wGo to build folder and open OpenCV.sln file with Visual Studio.
  e created above.
- Click on Configure and select X64 platform and hit Finish.
- New options will appear in CMake in red color. Tick these checkboxes
  there: WITH_CUDA, OPENCV_DNN_CUDA, ENABLE_FAST_MATH
- On the same window, go to OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH and browse for
  OpenCV contrib directory and point to the modules subfolder.
- Hit Configure again. You will see new options in red color. Tick
  CUDA_FAST_MATH checkbox. From CUDA_ARCH_BIN property, remove any
  compute architecture that your model of nVidia GPU does not support.
  You can find a list of compatible compute architectures for your
  model of GPU.
- Hit Configure and then Generate.

**Step 2: Making OpenCV with Visual Studio**

- Go to build folder and open OpenCV.sln file with Visual Studio.
- Once opened, change Debug to Release from the top.
- On the panel at the right-hand side, expand Cmake Targets.
- Right-click on ALL_BUILD and click on build.
- Once done, right-click on Install and click on build.

**Verify GPU Computation Speedup**

Here is a small code that performs simple matrix multiplication on CPU using NumPy and on GPU using OpenCV.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

npTmp = np.random.random((1024, 1024)).astype(np.float32)

npMat1 = np.stack([npTmp,npTmp],axis=2)
npMat2 = npMat1

cuMat1 = cv.cuda_GpuMat()
cuMat2 = cv.cuda_GpuMat()
cuMat1.upload(npMat1)
cuMat2.upload(npMat2)

print(%timeit cv.cuda.gemm(cuMat1, cuMat2,1,None,0,None,1))
print(%timeit cv.gemm(npMat1,npMat2,1,None,0,None,1))
```

Comment: Solved the problem by building with cmake(CUI) and Ninja. CV2 folder was successfully added in site-packages folder.